# How to use pointers to hashtable values in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, hash, hashtable

What I would like to have is for many components to have internal class variables which house some local information pertaining to the class. They get updated internally as the component runs.

```
public class myclass_1
{ 
    public Hashtable housekeeping_hash = new Hashtable();
    ...
    housekeeping_hash.Add('foo',(double)value1);
    housekeeping_hash.Add('bar',(double)value2);
    ...
```

I will have many different classes, all with a housekeeping hashtable internal to it.

```
public class myclass_2
{ 
    public Hashtable housekeeping_hash = new Hashtable();
    ....
    housekeeping_hash.Add('sunset',(double)value3);
    housekeeping_hash.Add('sunrise',(double)value90);
    ...
```

What I would like to have is another class which can record pointers to each of the `myclass_#` hashtable values, and then report those values at a later time. Something like:

```
public class housekeeper
{
    public void find_housekeeping_hashes
    {
        //foreach (myclass in all_of_myclasses)
        {
            Hashtable hTable = myclass.IGetHash();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Entry in hTable )
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    //_items is a class with 'Name' and 'Data' accessible attributes
                    _items.Add(new HousekeepingItem((string)Entry.Key, &((double)Entry.Value)));
                }              
            }
        }
    }
    public void reportHousekeeping()
    {
        //every N seconds
        foreach (HousekeepingItem item in _items)
            {
                double val = (double) *(_item.Data);
                result += "," + item.Name + "|" + val.ToString();
            }
    }
```

That is the general idea. I'd like to be able to do this quickly for many components so am trying to use pointers just to report each housekeeping hashtable. But I get an error when I'm trying to record the address of `&((double)Entry.Value)`. The error is: `Error: Cannot take the address of the given expression`.

Is such a thing even possible? I am new to C#, and wonder if hashtables and their elements can even be fixed in memory, and their entry keys and values 'pointed' to. I have tried many variations of the pseudo code above and meet similar issues.

Comment: `What I would like to have is for many components to have internal class variables which house some local information pertaining to the class` - I think you might be looking for [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: BTW, forget memory, C# is not C++. Create proper strongly typed properties, or use a `Dictionary<string,double>` or something like that. forget `unsafe`, you don't need that

Comment: Also, it would seem that `myclass_1` and `myclass_2` should inherit from a base `MyBaseClass` (also please fix your naming conventions as an aside), which would declare the Dictionary stuff. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: This question will probably be closed as Too Broad, as there are a number of fundamental issues that need to be dealt with here - you are trying to use C++ in a C# way (or is it C# in a C++ way).  IN any case, your Google searches specific to this question should probably include (at a minimum) "properties," "interface," and "Reflection".  Pointers and addressing are rarely used in C#, unless (for example) interfacing with existing C++/Windows API's, and your case above, unfortunately, is no different.

Comment: I also would like to add few points: 1) please read about StringBuilder... adding a lot of strings to your report using += is not a good way. 2) if all this thing is written to perform Logging, please take a look at logging frameworks like NLog for example. It is not clear from the question what for hosekeeping collections are used except logging. 3) use one singletone dictionary or hashtable globally, accesible from all your classes, do not encapsulate it inside each class if it is needed globally.

Comment: Okay, I was worried that this would be too broad. I am using interfaces for much of this, but tried to keep the post short so didn't include any mention of them here. I am coming from a C++ background, so that might be part of the problem. I will look into reflections though, because I am using the other two

Comment: @zachd1_618 I really think you `don't` need reflection for this either. Maybe you should edit the question explaining what do you want all this for to begin with. Looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Comment: These guys are right; everything you would typically use a pointer for in C/C++ you should simply use a reference for. Stop thinking about referencing and dereferencing pointers to storage as something you do and let the compiler take care of it for you. Let the hash tables take care of their own storage; you make references to the hash tables and instruct them to do your bidding. Raise the level of abstraction.